# All my siteweb page redirect to contact page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301

I Have an issue with my WordPress website every page is redirecting to the contact.php page.

For example, I click on the homepage, I get the contact page. When I check the network section in the browser inspector I have something like this :

```
302 get www.domaine.com (homepage but with 302 code!).

301 get www.domaine.com/index.php?page_id=5672 (I think the page_id is for contact page).

200 get www.domaine.com/contact.php .
```

then the page contact.php is loaded.

I get this for every page of my website, but when I logged in admin panel everything works OK, I think the problem shows up when I updated WordPress to the newest version but not sure about that.

edit : htacces file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you installed any redirect plugin?

Comment: Hi, yes i have plugin for redirecting the login and admin panel and for hide some wp stuff, its worked normally, but i delete it and clean the .htacces from there code , nothing happened, the problem still here.

Comment: Is your actual site www.domaine.com? If not, please edit your question to use example.com ([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)).

Comment: @WaiHaLee I'm not sure that's crucial info to edit xD

Comment: can we your .htaccess file?

Comment: hm, so there is nothing doing it via the htaccess file. Can we see the plugin data?

Comment: hi, like i said, i delete the plugin and the data before think this will solve the problem, so can't show this data.

Comment: @CheMsoV ah I see! Erm.. in that case not sure, is there a place in WordPress to set up redirects?

Comment: @treyBake there no other plugin or something like that, but in the code of wordpress maybe, dont know where to check ...